# Ubuntu 14.04 installation on via EPIA M910

Tags: system-installation, via

Had some trouble installing 14.04 desktop on VIA EPIA-M910 with VX900 chipset. Part way through the installation the screen goes blank so you cant interact with the installer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Thank you for sharing your knowledge!  However, could you [edit] your question and cut-and-paste the answer in the answer section below your question???  After a few days, come back and then accept your own answer by clicking the **☑** button next to your answer.  Then all other users will see a question with [a valid answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking VIA about this here is the resolution:

use xforcevesa to force to use VESA Driver first.  So when it boots up, F6 then ESC then type xforcevesa to boot.

Hope this helps somebody.